# GridView hyperlink for Date field is not displaying using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="637px" CssClass="auto-style1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="TimeStamp" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Logs.aspx?TimeStamp={0}" DataTextField="TimeStamp" HeaderText="TIME STAMP"></asp:HyperLinkField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource  ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SoneilCloudRemConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [TimeStamp] FROM [SensorLogData] WHERE ([deviceId] = @deviceId)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="121313131" Name="deviceId" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The above is the code snippet used for displaying date with hyperlink. For me it displays just the date instead of it to be hyperlink. In my SQL the datatype for this date is in "datetime" format.

I tried using other field to display in hyperlink, it's working. Finding issue only for datetime.

Answer (score 0):

The Gridview won't build a URL containing `:` (which is in the time portion of `Timestamp`). This results in an `<a>` tag being created with no `href`.

If you can live without the time, you can change the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` to only use the date portion:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Logs.aspx?TimeStamp={0:d}"
```

Another option is described [here](https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/609053-asp-net-2-0-hyperlink-datanavigateurlformatstring). It would involve formatting `Timestamp` to a specific format & then parsing the querystring `Timestamp` using `DateTime.ParseExact().

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Logs.aspx?TimeStamp={0:yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss}"
```

Then on `Logs.aspx`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Request.QueryString("Timestamp").ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks @itsPete, this worked DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Logs.aspx?TimeStamp={0:d}" to give me  href.